# Passing a props value to an external function in Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a page showing details of a User and need to display the invoices belonging to that user.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            // Child component one .....
        </div>
        <div>
            // Child component two .....
        </div>

        <div>
            // Invoice component one .....
            <invoice-list :vendor-id="vendorData.id"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have a JS file that calls the API to fetch the data, imported in the invoice template. I am trying to get the vendorId in that JS file so that it can be passed as a param.

My invoice template looks like:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Table Container grid -->
        ---------
        ---------
        ---------
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onUnmounted } from '@vue/composition-api'
import store from '@/store'
import useInvoicesList from './useInvoiceList'
import invoiceStoreModule from '../invoiceStoreModule'


export default {
  props: {
    vendorId: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    
    const {
      fetchInvoices,
      refetchData,
    } = useInvoicesList()

    return {
      fetchInvoices,
      refetchData,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

My useInvoiceList.js looks like:

```
import { ref, watch, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'
import store from '@/store'

export default function useInvoicesList() {

  const refInvoiceListTable = ref(null)

  const fetchInvoices = (ctx, callback) => {
    store
      .dispatch('app-invoice/fetchInvoices', {
        q: searchQuery.value,
        **/*This is where I need the vendor ID*/**
      })
      .then(response => {
       
      })
      .catch(() => {
        
      })
  }

  return {
    fetchInvoices,
    refInvoiceListTable,
    refetchData,
  }
}
```

How would I get the vendor ID in the fetchInvoices method?

Comment: Just pass it as a argument to `fetchInvoices` function

Comment: @MichalLevý, sorry new to Vuejs so my comment might be silly. Did you mean I pass vendorId like this  `const fetchInvoices = (ctx, callback, vendorId) => {`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set the variable value in the store and use it directly in your js file as you are already importing store in it another way you can pass parameters to fetchInvoices(props.vendorId).

Comment: Tried `const fetchInvoices = (ctx, callback, props.vendorId) => {}` but not sure how the vendorId would be available to this function.

Comment: dear pass props.vendorId from the component  
setup(props) {
    
    const {
      fetchInvoices,
      refetchData,
    } = useInvoicesList()

    return {
      fetchInvoices(prop.vendorId),
      refetchData,
    }
  },
and then receive it in the js file where you declare the function

Comment: Getting error ```Unexpected token, expected "{" (366:27)``` while passing a variable as ```return { fetchInvoices(prop.vendorId), refetchData, } }```

Comment: try  const {
      fetchInvoices(prop.vendorId),
      refetchData,
    } = useInvoicesList() 
and remove (prop.vendorId) from return where it is giving error

Comment: Getting same error: ```Unexpected token (344:19)```

Comment: there is some issue with the syntax cant figure out what is it try calling function differently but definetlly the argument is gonna pass this way

Comment: Thanks @Meeran! For now, I have used `id: router.currentRoute.params.id,` i.e. get the vendor id from the route params, not sure if it is the correct approach. Thoughts?

Comment: yeah kind of but you should use store it will be  straight and easy and acceptable way make state variable set its value = id and then fetch it from store in js file its the right way